# Parse push sending and receiving, not getting ParsePushBroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, parse-platform, notifications

How do I get the push and send the push.
     I want to receive push message and display the message on an activity,
     I've tried the following, but ParsePushBrodcastReciver is not found.

I'm able to send it and it is received, but I can't get the message     to hold in some variable

```
package com.parse.starter;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;


public class ParsePushReciever extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {


@Override
public void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
    AppLog.e("Push", "Clicked");
    Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    i.putExtras(intent.getExtras());
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(i);
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("Push Notification",intent.getExtras().get(ParsePushBroadcastReceiver.KEY_PUSH_DATA).toString());
    NotificationManager nm=(NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.launcher);

    Intent newIntent=new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
    newIntent.putExtra(context.getString(R.string.navigation_from_notification),true);
    newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, newIntent, 0);

    builder.setContentIntent(pi);

    builder.setContentText("Push Notification");

    Log.d("Notification", strMsg);

    nm.notify(1, builder.build());
}
}
```

Comment: Could you post your manifest?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void generateNotification(Context context, String title, String message, String action) {
  // Show the notification
  NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setContentTitle(title).setContentText(message)
        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher));
  Intent intent = new Intent(context, SplashScreen.class);
  intent.putExtra(KEY_TITLE, title);
  intent.putExtra(KEY_BODY, message);
  intent.setAction(action);
  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
  Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
  mBuilder.setSound(soundUri);
  // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app

  TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
  stackBuilder.addParentStack(SplashScreen.class);
  stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
  PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
  mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
  NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
  // used for random integer generation
  mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
  Random random = new Random();

  mNotificationManager.notify(random.nextInt(), mBuilder.build());
  Vibrator v = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
  // Vibrate for 500 milliseconds
  if (v != null)
     v.vibrate(1000);
  }
```

Try this code to generate notification and open the notification with the required message in the Intent.

Answer (score 0):

This little code can get all the text from a push, you can do your things with it:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
    JSONObject json = null;
    try {
        json = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));
        String text = json.getString("alert").toString();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

just put it inside your onReceive() method.

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

I find useful example

```
public class MyCustomReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
   private static final String TAG = "MyCustomReceiver";
   public static final String intentAction = "SEND_PUSH";

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       if (intent == null) {
           Log.d(TAG, "Receiver intent null");
       } else {
          // Parse push message and handle accordingly
          processPush(context, intent);
       }
   }

   private void processPush(Context context, Intent intent) {
       String action = intent.getAction();
       Log.d(TAG, "got action " + action );
       if (action.equals(intentAction))
       {
           String channel = intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Channel");
           try {        
               JSONObject json = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));
               Log.d(TAG, "got action " + action + " on channel " + channel + " with:");
               // Iterate the parse keys if needed
               Iterator<String> itr = json.keys();
               while (itr.hasNext()) {
                   String key = (String) itr.next();
               // Extract custom push data
               if (key.equals("customdata")) {    
                // Handle push notification by invoking activity directly
                launchSomeActivity(context, json.getString(key));
                // OR trigger a broadcast to activity
                triggerBroadcastToActivity(context);
                // OR create a local notification
                createNotification(context);
                }
                    Log.d(TAG, "..." + key + " => " + json.getString(key));
               }
            } catch (JSONException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "JSON failed!");
            }
       }
   }

   public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 45;
   // Create a local dashboard notification to tell user about the event
   private void createNotification(Context context) {
       NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context).setSmallIcon(
               R.drawable.ic_launcher).setContentTitle("Successfully logged in");
       NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
       mNotificationManager.notify(45, mBuilder.build());
   }

   // Handle push notification by invoking activity directly
   private void launchSomeActivity(Context context, String datavalue) {
       Intent pupInt = new Intent(context, ShowPopUp.class);
       pupInt.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
       pupInt.putExtra("customdata", datavalue);
       context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(pupInt);   
   }

   // Handle push notification by sending a local broadcast 
   // to which the activity subscribes to
   private void triggerBroadcastToActivity(Context context) {
       LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(new Intent(intentAction));
   }
}
```

for this ... this will help you

https://github.com/codepath/ParsePushNotificationExample

and dont forget to add broadcast Receiver to Manifest

```
 <receiver
        android:name=".MyReceiver"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```